# Got a SIGABRT while executing native code while running Asp.Net MVC3 + MySql on CentOs

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mono, sigabrt

I've been trying to get MVC3 website working on an apache server on CentOs 6.5. Mono seems to work fine, I can run a simple MVC3 site nicely, but when I add MySql connector to my project I get a "Internal Server Error" on the page and a long httpd log error stating:

"Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries used by your application."

I can't seem to find a way past this, can anyone help me solve this problem or advice on which packages and versions should I be using if my current setup is not the recommended way? My goal is to build a MVC3 site with connection to MySql db, I'd greatly appreciate help on this.

I'm using .Net Framework 4. I added NuGet packages MySql.Data 6.8.3 and MySql.Data.Entity 6.7.5, and my EntityFramework is version 5.0.0.

I've set the copy local property to true on the following assemblies:

System.Web.Helpers
System.Web.Mvc
System.Web.Providers
System.Web.Razor
System.Web.Routing
System.Web.WebPages
System.Web.WebPages.Razor
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment

... and specifically false to Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.

Here's some more details:

In the log I get in httpd error_log there is one readable error (besides what I think are mono stacktrace entries etc):

```
    Native stacktrace:

    /opt/mono/bin/mono() [0x80f0412]
    [0xb7785600]

    Debug info from gdb:

    warning: File "/opt/mono/bin/mono-sgen-gdb.py" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "/usr/share/gdb/auto-load:/usr/lib/debug:/usr/bin/mono-gdb.py".
    To enable execution of this file add
    add-auto-load-safe-path /opt/mono/bin/mono-sgen-gdb.py
    line to your configuration file "$HOME/.gdbinit".
    To completely disable this security protection add
    set auto-load safe-path /
    line to your configuration file "$HOME/.gdbinit".
    For more information about this security protection see the
    "Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
    info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
```

I don't understand much about python scripts but I don't think I should have to adjust such things just to get a simple website working. Without knowing much I tried to create a file .gdbinit and added that line, but it has no effect.

---

Ok, new developments: 
As instructed I uninstalled my mono and mod_mono installation from under /opt/mono and installed everything back using prefix /usr.

Something is still off, now I can restart httpd with no errors like before but running my mvc3 site causes a nullreferenceexception in the httpd error log:

```
    Worker initialization exception occurred. Continuing anyway:
    System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
      at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
      at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorkerRequest..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

    Server stack trace:
      at Mono.WebServer.BaseApplicationHost.EndOfRequest (Mono.WebServer.MonoWorkerRequest mwr) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
      at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoApplicationHost.ProcessRequest (Int32 reqId, System.String verb, System.String queryString, System.String path, System.String protocol, System.String localAddress, Int32 serverPort, System.String remoteAddress, Int32 remotePort, System.String remoteName, System.String[] headers, System.String[] headerValues, System.Object worker) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
      at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.WebServer.ModMonoApplicationHost:ProcessRequest (int,string,string,string,string,string,int,string,int,string,string[],string[],object)
      at (wrapper xdomain-dispatch) Mono.WebServer.ModMonoApplicationHost:ProcessRequest (object,byte[]&,byte[]&,int,string,string,string,string,string,int,string,int,string,string[],string[])

    Exception rethrown at [0]:

      at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) Mono.WebServer.ModMonoApplicationHost:ProcessRequest (int,string,string,string,string,string,int,string,int,string,string[],string[],object)
      at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.WebServer.ModMonoApplicationHost:ProcessRequest (int,string,string,string,string,string,int,string,int,string,string[],string[],object)
      at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorker.InnerRun (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
      at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorker.Run (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
    [Thu May 08 15:38:55 2014] [error] (70014)End of file found: read_data failed
    [Thu May 08 15:38:55 2014] [error] Command stream corrupted, last command was -1
```

Any ideas what could be causing this? I have following additions on mod_mono.conf:

MonoServerPath "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"
MonoAutoApplication enabled
MonoUnixSocket /tmp/mod_mono_server_global
MonoTargetFramework "4.0"

And my website is configured in httpd.conf:

```
    Alias /boacommander_simple "/var/www/html/boacommander_simple"
    MonoApplications "/boacommander_simple:/var/www/html/boacommander_simple"
    <Location /boacommander_simple>
       SetHandler mono
    </Location>
```

As before mono version is 3.2.8 and mod_mono 2.10. Using framework 4.0.

Thanks guys if you can spare some advice.

---

Some more info on this:

Running xsp4 will produce the following output on console:

```
# xsp4
Missing method System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler::Create(object,object,XmlNode) in assembly /usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.dll, referenced in assembly /usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Configuration.dll
Exception caught during reading the configuration file:
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler.Create'.
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection (System.String configKey) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.get_AppSettings () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server+ApplicationSettings..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
xsp4
Listening on address: 0.0.0.0
Root directory: /
Listening on port: 8080 (non-secure)
Hit Return to stop the server.

Missing method System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty::.ctor(string,Type,object,TypeConverter,ConfigurationValidatorBase,ConfigurationPropertyOptions) in assembly /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll, referenced in assembly /usr/lib/mono/4.0/System.Web.dll
Exception during TraceManager initialization:
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Web.Configuration.TraceSection ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty..ctor'.
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Web.TraceManager..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

There are a few similar problems out there but no answers on what's causing the problem or how to fix it.

---

I updated mono to 3.4.1 and reinstalled mod_mono and xsp. I still get errors but those must be unrelated to my original question. I'll leave this one open, in case someone else gets similar results using the same versions I did. I've upgraded my mono and got new problems, I'll ask about those in another post.

Comment: what version of mono are you using and how did you install it?

Comment: Mono version is 3.2.8, I installed it from source using prefix /opt/mono.

Comment: did you remove mono packages from centOs first?

Comment: Honestly it's been so long that I've worked on this I don't remember, but I couldn't find any mono packages on the machine so I'd say I must have. :)

Comment: then try uninstalling your mono, and reinstall in /usr instead of /opt/mono, because /opt/mono is usually meant to be used only for multi-mono parallel installations

Comment: I was afraid someone would say this, took me ages to get a mono installation working with basic websites. But I will try that, as I don't intend to run multiple versions of mono. Thank you for the advice. Any idea though on what might be causing my problem with the mysql connector? Does it have something to do with the mono prefix, environment variables, paths etc? Would be good to understand the problem in case others run into the same thing.

Comment: /opt/mono is simply not a standard prefix, and many things can go wrong when using it; you would need to learn more linuxy stuff to understand...

Comment: (That being said, mono shouldn't crash, so if you keep running into the same problem after switching prefix and making sure there are no standard CentOS packages installed, try upgrading to mono 3.4.0 first, and use gdb to debug later, as a last resort.)

Comment: Thanks, I will try to learn more linuxy stuff. And try to fix the installation under /usr and see if there is improvement.

Comment: So far I installed mono 3.4.1 from git, and reinstalled mod_mono and xsp. Still no luck. I updated the results to my original question.